Real time vechile tracking using django channels and react
I want to implement real time tracking for vehicles but I don't know most of my things are not working. I use the geolocation API to get current device location and send those locations(latitude, longitude) to backend every five seconds. Then using django channels and Daphne I implement routing APIs I will use in react with the websockets but things take a delay to respond. I was requesting for yhe way I can design the database efficiently and the way I can handle the websocket connections
I tried to create the real time tracking using leaflet maps so that I can see the image move smoothly on the map but it just jumps or let me say it doesn't work as expected
